# Kotlin - Lists operations between lists with different T's

Tags: kotlin, generics, collections

I stumbled upon a bug in my code that I thought would be noticed & prevented by the compilation:

```
val ints: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val uuids: MutableList<UUID> = mutableListOf(UUID.randomUUID())

// No compilation error here:
val result = uuids.intersect(ints)

// Compilation error here, as expected
uuids.add(1)
```

IJ mentions that `result` is of type `Set<{Comparable<*> & Serializable}>`

And intersect signature seems correct:
`public infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.intersect(other: Iterable<T>): Set<T> {`

My bug was that I just checked wether the intersection was empty, thus not seeing that by comparing incompatible objects, that would always be true.

So do I miss something obvious?
Thanks

Comment: It’s not prevented by compilation because it’s valid code. Sometimes a bug is just your fault for not noticing it. ;)

Comment: As IntelliJ says, if `T` is `{Comparable<*> & Serializable}`, the call is valid. You can't actually denote this type in Kotlin, but it still exists in the type system.

Comment: It's not limited to `intersect`. The code compiles with all other non-modifying operations on any two collections. Try, for example, `val whatsthis = uuids + ints`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that it's a bit surprising that it is valid to call `intersect` with `List` objects of two different types. However, this is an inevitable consequence of Kotlin's type inference system and the type projection on `List` objects.

###### Type inference

No type is specified in your call `uuids.intersect(ints)` so Kotlin checks to see if a type exists that makes the call valid, and for the most specific type that the output can be. The answer to that there is such a type so the call is valid; and that type is a `Set` of `Comparable<*> & Serializable` objects. Thus Kotlin makes that type the generic type `T` for the call.

This is the case because both `List<UUID>` and `List<Int>` are both subtypes of `List<Comparable<*> & Serializable>` (not that you can write that intersection type in Kotlin<sup>1</sup>). In turn, this is true because both `UUID` and `Int` are subtypes of both `Comparable<*>` and `Serializable`, and `List`s are covariant<sup>2</sup>.

I don't see any way the signature of the function `intersect` could be written to avoid this problem, barring some special Kotlin annotation to change the usual type inference algorithm.

###### Invariant types

Instead, if you have a function of the form:

```
fun <T> GenericType<T>.doSomething(target: GenericType<T>)
```

and `GenericType` was invariant (ie no type projection) then you will get an error if you try to call it with an argument `GenericType<S>` (where `S` is not the same as `T`). I suspect this case you would more often come across, and this would not give surprising results.

###### Specifying a type

If you specify the type for your call, either as the type of `result` or the generic type of the call as `UUID` (the type you were surely expecting), then you do get an error:

```
val result: Set<UUID> = uuids.intersect(ints) // type mismatch error
val result = uuids.intersect<UUID>(ints) // type mismatch error
```

In such cases, there is no type inference to do and the compiler can immediately see there is a mismatch.

---

<sup>1</sup> See the [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108) for the feature request

<sup>2</sup> ie [`out` projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) types, meaning a `List<A>` is a subtype of `List<B>` if `A` is a subtype of `B`